# can't transfer and register a Canceled+/Expired .Li domain (with incomplete WHOIS)

Tags: domains, dns, whois, transfer, expired-domains

I contacted the registrant (I edited out his name out below) by finding his new email on the web, he emailed me that he don't own the domain anymore and sent photos he took of the paper forms he filled, titled "domain cancellation" dating back from August 2017.

a Support Operator from [One.com](http://One.com) tells me the domain is expired since 11th of January 2018, and that I can't register it, she can only send Auth ID to the "email of the registrant". but according to [their policy](https://www.one.com/en/domain-registration-agreement), the domain is well after it's expiry and redemption period.

he says he lost his old email that he used to register the domain, and that he might not be able to get access to the Auth ID.

I want to transfer it manually with a support operator to my registrar of choice.
What can I do?

Here's the WHOIS response for the domain, note that there's no update and expiry dates.

```
whois: This information is subject to an Acceptable Use Policy.
See https://www.nic.ch/terms/aup/


Domain name:
example.li

Holder of domain name:
First Last
Address Somewhere
BE-1800 Brussel
Belgium

Technical contact:
One.com
Jacob Jensen
Kalvebod Brygge 45
DK-1560 Copenhagen V
Denmark

Registrar:
Ascio Technologies Inc. Danmark

First registration date:
2007-05-30

DNSSEC:N

Name servers:
ns01.one.com
ns02.one.com
```

Comment: You should contact the registry (Switch) or the registrar (Ascio) for any question about the domain name, not its technical provider.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the registrant will have to reregister the domain in order to transfer it to you. Since it's past the redemption period, this may not be possible. Technically, the registrar now may own the rights to sell the domain.

You see this happen with registars like Godaddy. When a domain goes to expiry, the domain doesn't actually drop or get caught. It stays with Godaddy. Godaddy can then sell it to the highest bidder.

Because the domain that you want is past redemption, you may have to wait until it actually drops until getting it. You can contact the registar and see if they will sell it to you, or allow the previous/current owner of the domain to transfer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything.  You can't transfer a domain that doesn't belong to you.  There isn't a manual process that goes around this restriction.  Restore is only offered to the owner of a domain.   A domain can not be transferred during the redemption period and even then, the current owner would need to be able to unlock the domain.

If the domain can be restored, only the most recent owner can restore the domain.  He can then sell the domain to you, but if he isn't able or willing to do that, you will need to wait until the domain is released back to the public

Comment: " You can't transfer a domain that doesn't belong to you." This is not absolutely true in all cases. For example in `.FR` the `recover` operation forces a transfer when the current registrant is not available anymore.